# EclipseLink Partitioning Annotations

Tags: postgresql, eclipselink

I was trying out @RoundRobinPartitioning with EclipseLink. I am seeing a weird issue. I have a test which inserts mock data in Postgres 9.2 (I have two instance of Postgres 9.2 running). The replication works fine (I have set replicateWrites to true). But when I run test queries on the cluster - the same queries runs slower on one instance vs. another. When I looked at the query plan both databases generated different query plans for the exact same data/indexes etc.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - running Analyze and Reindex on the table solved the problem.